# iOS app with no Bluetooth functionality is showing up under Bluetooth sharing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, ios9

An app we're working on was originally going to have Bluetooth enabled. After experimenting, we determined Bluetooth was not reliable enough for how we wanted to use it.

The settings in the app project were removed: Bluetooth background modes, and removed and deleted Bluetooth frameworks from the project. Deleted the app from the test device, cleaned and rebuilt. But the app is still showing up under Bluetooth sharing. This is under Settings, then Privacy, then Bluetooth Sharing. Also if the app is opened in Settings, Bluetooth appears as one of the options to "allow App to access".

My experience with the app reviewers is that any kind of inconsistency like this will raise flags during the review process.

Has anyone seen this before and fixed it?

Comment: Where exactly is your app appearing?  What is "Bluetooth sharing"?

Comment: Under Settings, then Privacy, then Bluetooth Sharing. Also if the app is opened in Settings, Bluetooth appears as one of the options to "allow App to access".

Comment: You need to check your apps background mode entitlements in the info.plist

Comment: Yes, have removed all background modes, and even turned off background processing completely. Also deleted the derived data and deleted the app from the test device.

Comment: unzip your IPA and check the info.plist. Install on another device or the simulator and check the settings there

Comment: The IPA looks clean and when installed in the simulator looks okay. Guess it's a quirk of debugging.